# MySQL “IN” operator run slow on large amount of value with left join and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table with 20043428 postings. When I query table with a select statement, using IN operator on ownerId field with large amount of value, it run in very slow query times (>2second).  Here's the schema of the story table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Story` (
  `storyId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `storyType` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `parentStoryId` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ownerId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lockroomId` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `isHost` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `updatedAt` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `createdAt` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `message` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `imageUrl` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `privacy` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `minutes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `hasCoinBadge` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `hasFriendBadge` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `localDBId` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `tagName` varchar(63) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `tagColor` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `tagId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numLikes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `numComments` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `lastCommenterId` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastCommentTimestamp` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `lastComment` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondLastCommenterId` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondLastCommentTimestamp` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `secondLastComment` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastLikerId` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `jointStoryInfo` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `milestoneImageUrl` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`storyId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `StoryId_UNIQUE` (`storyId`),
  KEY `ownerId` (`ownerId`),
  KEY `parentStoryId` (`parentStoryId`),
  KEY `updatedAt` (`updatedAt`),
  KEY `ownerId_updatedAt` (`ownerId`,`updatedAt`),
  KEY `updatedAt_ownerId_descending_index` (`updatedAt` DESC,`ownerId`),
  KEY `lockroomId` (`lockroomId`),
  KEY `combine_lockroomId_Index` (`storyType`,`lockroomId`),
  KEY `combine_storyType_createdAt_index` (`storyType`,`ownerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `ownerId` FOREIGN KEY (`ownerId`) REFERENCES `User` (`userId`),
  CONSTRAINT `parentStoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`parentStoryId`) REFERENCES `Story` (`storyId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20043428 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------------------+
| Field                      | Type                | Null | Key | Default              | Extra             |
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------------------+
| storyId                    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                 | auto_increment    |
| storyType                  | int(11)             | YES  |     | 0                    |                   |
| parentStoryId              | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL                 |                   |
| ownerId                    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                 |                   |
| lockroomId                 | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL                 |                   |
| isHost                     | tinyint(1)          | YES  |     | 0                    |                   |
| updatedAt                  | timestamp(6)        | YES  | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| createdAt                  | timestamp(6)        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| message                    | text                | YES  |     | NULL                 |                   |
| imageUrl                   | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL                 |                   |
| amount                     | int(11)             | YES  |     | NULL                 |                   |
| location                   | varchar(45)         | YES  |     | NULL                 |                   |
| privacy                    | tinyint(1)          | NO   |     | 0                    |                   |
| minutes                    | int(11)             | YES  |     | 0                    |                   |
| hasCoinBadge               | tinyint(1)          | YES  |     | 0                    |                   |
| hasFriendBadge             | tinyint(1)          | YES  |     | 0                    |                   |
| localDBId                  | text                | YES  |     | NULL                 |                   |
| tagName                    | varchar(63)         | YES  |     |                      |                   |
| tagColor                   | varchar(15)         | YES  |     |                      |                   |
| tagId                      | bigint(20)          | YES  |     | NULL                 |                   |
| numLikes                   | int(11)             | YES  |     | 0                    |                   |
| numComments                | int(11)             | YES  |     | 0                    |                   |
| lastCommenterId            | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL                 |                   |
| lastCommentTimestamp       | timestamp(6)        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| lastComment                | varchar(256)        | YES  |     | NULL                 |                   |
| secondLastCommenterId      | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL                 |                   |
| secondLastCommentTimestamp | timestamp(6)        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| secondLastComment          | varchar(256)        | YES  |     | NULL                 |                   |
| lastLikerId                | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL                 |                   |
+----------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------------------+
```

Here is the index of Story Table:

```
+-------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                           | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Story |          0 | PRIMARY                            |            1 | storyId       | A         |    19350090 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          0 | StoryId_UNIQUE                     |            1 | storyId       | A         |    19350090 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | ownerId                            |            1 | ownerId       | A         |     1255716 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | parentStoryId                      |            1 | parentStoryId | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | updatedAt                          |            1 | updatedAt     | A         |    19350090 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | ownerId_updatedAt                  |            1 | ownerId       | A         |     1743714 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | ownerId_updatedAt                  |            2 | updatedAt     | A         |    19350090 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | updatedAt_ownerId_descending_index |            1 | updatedAt     | D         |    19139564 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | updatedAt_ownerId_descending_index |            2 | ownerId       | A         |    18636190 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | lockroomId                         |            1 | lockroomId    | A         |      328860 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_lockroomId_Index           |            1 | storyType     | A         |         685 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_lockroomId_Index           |            2 | lockroomId    | A         |      221470 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_storyType_createdAt_index  |            1 | storyType     | A         |         542 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_storyType_createdAt_index  |            2 | ownerId       | A         |     1013545 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

And here's the query that takes >3 second to execute. What this query do is to get the all the Story that user in the ownerId set. As a result I use IN operator.

```
   SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ((SELECT 
        Story.*,
            jointStory.guestIds,
            jointStory.guestStoryIds,
            jointStory.guestTrees,
            jointStory.guestDurations
    FROM
        Story
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        lockroomId,
            GROUP_CONCAT(Story.ownerId) AS guestIds,
            GROUP_CONCAT(Story.storyId) AS guestStoryIds,
            GROUP_CONCAT(Story.imageUrl) AS guestTrees,
            GROUP_CONCAT(Story.minutes) AS guestDurations
    FROM
        Story
    WHERE
        Story.storyType = 1
            AND updatedAt < FROM_UNIXTIME(1600385817)
            AND lockroomId IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                lockroomId
            FROM
                Story
            WHERE
                ownerId IN (295840 , 657517, 853992, 887429, 895536, 938358, 1235164, 1240124, 1253845, 1272622, 1272677, 1302831, 1338671, 1395429, 1223590)
                    AND Story.storyType = 1
                    AND lockroomId IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY Story.lockroomId) jointStory ON jointStory.lockroomId = Story.lockroomId
    WHERE
        Story.storyType = 2
            AND Story.privacy = 0
            AND Story.updatedAt < FROM_UNIXTIME(1600385817)
            AND ownerId IN (295840 , 657517, 853992, 887429, 895536, 938358, 1235164, 1240124, 1253845, 1272622, 1272677, 1302831, 1338671, 1395429, 1223590)
            AND Story.lockroomId IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Story.lockroomId
    ORDER BY updatedAt DESC
    LIMIT 10) UNION ALL (SELECT 
        Story.*, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM
        Story
    WHERE
        Story.storyType = 0 AND privacy = 0
            AND ownerId IN (295840 , 657517, 853992, 887429, 895536, 938358, 1235164, 1240124, 1253845, 1272622, 1272677, 1302831, 1338671, 1395429, 1223590)
            AND updatedAt < FROM_UNIXTIME(1600385817)
    ORDER BY updatedAt DESC
    LIMIT 10)) newsFeed
        LEFT JOIN
    StoryEngagement ON StoryEngagement.storyId = newsFeed.storyId
        AND StoryEngagement.userId = 1223590
ORDER BY updatedAt DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The result of the explain extended command on this query shows that MySQL is using filesort and using index condition:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                | key                               | key_len | ref                         | rows | filtered | Extra                                                                                           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                         | NULL                              | NULL    | NULL                        |   12 |   100.00 | Using filesort                                                                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | StoryEngagement | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                      | PRIMARY                           | 16      | const,newsFeed.storyId      |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                                                                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | Story           | NULL       | range  | ownerId,updatedAt,ownerId_updatedAt,updatedAt_ownerId_descending_index,lockroomId,combine_lockroomId_Index,combine_storyType_createdAt_index | combine_storyType_createdAt_index | 13      | NULL                        |  124 |     0.51 | Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR; Using temporary; Using filesort                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3>      | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>                                                                                                                                  | <auto_key0>                       | 9       | flora_test.Story.lockroomId |    2 |   100.00 | NULL                                                                                            |
|  3 | DERIVED     | Story           | NULL       | range  | ownerId,ownerId_updatedAt,lockroomId,combine_lockroomId_Index,combine_storyType_createdAt_index                                              | combine_storyType_createdAt_index | 13      | NULL                        |  169 |    10.17 | Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR; Using temporary; Using filesort; Start temporary |
|  3 | DERIVED     | Story           | NULL       | ref    | updatedAt,updatedAt_ownerId_descending_index,lockroomId,combine_lockroomId_Index,combine_storyType_createdAt_index                           | lockroomId                        | 9       | flora_test.Story.lockroomId |   58 |     0.10 | Using where; End temporary                                                                      |
|  5 | UNION       | Story           | NULL       | range  | ownerId,updatedAt,ownerId_updatedAt,updatedAt_ownerId_descending_index,combine_lockroomId_Index,combine_storyType_createdAt_index            | combine_storyType_createdAt_index | 13      | NULL                        | 3517 |     5.00 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort                                              |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It would be very appreciate if you have any ideas on how to optimize this query. It would be great if there is a way that do not need to create index and make this query run faster, because this is a huge production table and adding index take very long time, also adding some new index may cause other query run slower. I have already tried a few things such as creating a combined index on group by fields( `index(storyType,ownerId)`) as suggested by a few blog postings, but run even slower...

UPDATE

I rewrite the query as you suggested and I add those covering index.

```
INDEX(storyType, lockroomId, ownerId)
INDEX(storyType, privacy, ownerId)
INDEX(storyType, privacy, updatedAt)
```

Here is the index set of this table:

```
+-------+------------+---------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                              | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-------+------------+---------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Story |          0 | PRIMARY                               |            1 | storyId       | A         |    19350090 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          0 | StoryId_UNIQUE                        |            1 | storyId       | A         |    19350090 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | ownerId                               |            1 | ownerId       | A         |     1255716 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | parentStoryId                         |            1 | parentStoryId | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | updatedAt                             |            1 | updatedAt     | A         |    19350090 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | ownerId_updatedAt                     |            1 | ownerId       | A         |     1743714 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | ownerId_updatedAt                     |            2 | updatedAt     | A         |    19350090 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | updatedAt_ownerId_descending_index    |            1 | updatedAt     | D         |    19139564 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | updatedAt_ownerId_descending_index    |            2 | ownerId       | A         |    18636190 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | lockroomId                            |            1 | lockroomId    | A         |      328860 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_story_index                   |            1 | storyType     | A         |         429 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_story_index                   |            2 | lockroomId    | A         |      665208 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_story_index                   |            3 | createdAt     | A         |    19350090 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_story_index                   |            4 | ownerId       | A         |    19350090 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_story_privacy_ownerId_index   |            1 | storyType     | A         |         514 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_story_privacy_ownerId_index   |            2 | privacy       | A         |        1544 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_story_privacy_ownerId_index   |            3 | ownerId       | A         |     1924457 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_story_privacy_updatedAt_index |            1 | storyType     | A         |         527 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_story_privacy_updatedAt_index |            2 | privacy       | A         |        1582 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_story_privacy_updatedAt_index |            3 | updatedAt     | A         |    19350090 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_type_lockroomId_ownerId_index |            1 | storyType     | A         |         523 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_type_lockroomId_ownerId_index |            2 | lockroomId    | A         |      734891 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| Story |          1 | combine_type_lockroomId_ownerId_index |            3 | ownerId       | A         |     1267468 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-------+------------+---------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

However the query is still run slowly about 3.404sec.
Here is the `EXPLAIN SELECT`:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                         | key                                   | key_len | ref                            | rows  | filtered | Extra                                                                |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | NULL                                  | NULL    | NULL                           |    12 |   100.00 | Using filesort                                                       |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | StoryEngagement | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                               | PRIMARY                               | 16      | const,newsFeed.storyId         |     1 |   100.00 | Using where                                                          |
|  2 | DERIVED     | Story           | NULL       | range  | ownerId,updatedAt,ownerId_updatedAt,updatedAt_ownerId_descending_index,lockroomId,combine_story_index,combine_story_privacy_ownerId_index,combine_story_privacy_updatedAt_index,combine_type_lockroomId_ownerId_index | combine_story_privacy_ownerId_index   | 14      | NULL                           |    27 |     5.09 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3>      | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>                                                                                                                                                                                                           | <auto_key0>                           | 9       | flora_test.Story.lockroomId    |     2 |   100.00 | NULL                                                                 |
|  3 | DERIVED     | s3              | NULL       | ref    | ownerId,ownerId_updatedAt,lockroomId,combine_story_index,combine_story_privacy_ownerId_index,combine_story_privacy_updatedAt_index,combine_type_lockroomId_ownerId_index                                              | combine_type_lockroomId_ownerId_index | 5       | const                          | 36390 |     0.02 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort; LooseScan |
|  3 | DERIVED     | s2              | NULL       | ref    | updatedAt,updatedAt_ownerId_descending_index,lockroomId,combine_story_index,combine_story_privacy_ownerId_index,combine_story_privacy_updatedAt_index,combine_type_lockroomId_ownerId_index                           | combine_type_lockroomId_ownerId_index | 14      | const,flora_test.s3.lockroomId |    26 |    50.00 | Using where                                                          |
|  5 | UNION       | Story           | NULL       | range  | ownerId,updatedAt,ownerId_updatedAt,updatedAt_ownerId_descending_index,combine_story_index,combine_story_privacy_ownerId_index,combine_story_privacy_updatedAt_index,combine_type_lockroomId_ownerId_index            | combine_story_privacy_ownerId_index   | 14      | NULL                           |  3906 |    50.00 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort                   |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After testing, I think the upper side of the `UNION` is slower. And `LEFT JOIN  StoryEngagement` is necessary, because this table store all the likeId CommentId. As a result we need to join this table and get who comment or like on this story.

Thank you for helping me to solve the problem.

Comment: You might want to explain what you want the query to do.  There may be more efficient ways of writing it.

Comment: I want to get all the user's Story and some Story need to join together. As a result I As a result I need to group the story by lockroomId to create joinStory.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
            FROM  Story
            WHERE  Story.storyType = 1
              AND  updatedAt < FROM_UNIXTIME(1600385817)
              AND  lockroomId IN (
                 SELECT  DISTINCT lockroomId
                    FROM  Story
                    WHERE  ownerId IN (295840 , 657517, 853992, 887429, 895536,
                                938358, 1235164, 1240124, 1253845, 1272622,
                                1272677, 1302831, 1338671, 1395429, 1223590)
                       AND  Story.storyType = 1
                       AND  lockroomId IS NOT NULL
                                 )
```

See if this is any faster:

```
FROM  Story AS s2
WHERE  s2.storyType = 1
  AND  s2.updatedAt < FROM_UNIXTIME(1600385817)
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Story
                WHERE s3.ownerId IN (...)
                  AND s3.storyType = 1
                  AND s3.lockroomId = s2.lockroomId )
```

And have this "covering" index:

```
INDEX(storyType, lockroomId, ownerId)
```

Please qualify all columns with aliases.

---

For this

```
                   WHERE  Story.storyType = 2
                      AND  Story.privacy = 0
                      AND  Story.updatedAt < FROM_UNIXTIME(1600385817)
                      AND  ownerId IN (295840 , 657517, 853992, 887429, 895536,
                                938358, 1235164, 1240124, 1253845, 1272622, 1272677, 1302831,
                                1338671, 1395429, 1223590
                          )
                      AND  Story.lockroomId IS NOT NULL
```

have these

```
INDEX(storyType, privacy, ownerId)
INDEX(storyType, privacy, updatedAt)
```

(The Optimizer will pick which one is better.)

---

For `LEFT JOIN  StoryEngagement ...`, it is unclear whether having the join is needed and/or whether the `LEFT` has any effect.  It needs:

```
StoryEngagement:  INDEX(userId, storyId)  -- in either order
```

---

Which side of the `UNION` is slower?  Is it slow enough that we should focus on it and ignore (for now) the rest of the query?

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. Please check out my update. Thank you

Comment: @林振弘 - Would you see if the `newsfeed` subquery is consuming most of the time.  I _think_ that the final join to `StoryEngagement` and order-by and limit are fast.